# Maven - disable parent distributionManagement in child POM?

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

We are using third party parent pom where they defined own `distributionManagement`.

We are useing own server to publish artifacts. So whenever i am using `mvn clean deploy`, then application is trying to upload artifacts on parent server which is defined in parent `distributionManagement`.

Can anyone please provide any input to disable parent `distributionManagement`  in child pom.xml file?

Comment: As already mentioned just overwrite it...

Answer (score 3):

Just overwrite it.

You need it anyway to deploy, so there is no point in disabling it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for quick reply. It is working fine after override :)

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned you have your own server so you do NOT need to disable it. You need to overwrite the setting.

You should be able to define a new `<distributionManagement>` section in the child POM which will completely overwrite the settings from parent POM.